Reference Request: Module structure over the mod $p$ Steenrod algebra of the cohomology of cyclic groups of order $p$ for $p$ odd prime
Let $p$ be a prime number. Does anyone know  a reference for  the action of  the  mod $p$ steenrod algebra on the  cohomology  of cyclic groups  of  prime  order $p$ when  $p \neq 2$.  $p=3$ or  $p=5$ would be  nice.

I don't have a reference off the top of my head, but just wanted to point out that the action is directly determined by the axioms (instability + the Cartan formula) as well as the action of the Bockstein, analogously to the $p=2$ case.

The cohomology in your question is isomorphic to the mod $p$ cohomology of the Eilenberg–Mac Lane space $K(C_p,1)$. The mod $p$ cohomology of $K(C_p,n)$ was calculated for all $n\geq 1$ by Henri Cartan in the 1950s, including the ring structure and the Steenrod operations. The Cartan seminar version is here: Détermination des algèbres $H_*(\pi, n; Z_p)$ et $H^*(\pi, n; Z_p)$, $p$ premier impair and a journal version (IMO easier to read) is here: Sur les groupes de Eilenberg–Mac Lane. II. In particular, the $n=1$ case of Theorem 6 in the journal version is the result you're asking for.
